# How can I send a date from one site to other sites?

Tags: php

I'm not much of a php coder, mainly use VB. But I had a problem with one of my apps. To make it more secure I would need each php parameter to go through one site. Here is an example of what I mean:

- Application loads
- Sends ip and location to 2 servers (a.php & b.php)

The problem so far is that the PC is making direct connections to these pages. What I was trying to do is make it so that it only sends one command to `z.php` and the page `z.php` would send the data to `a.php` and `b.php`.

My question is: How would I set up `z.php`?

I hope this makes sense; I have looked everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have z.php make a GET request to a.php and b.php, passing the required parameters in the querystring.

i.e. a.php?parama=valuea&paramb=valueb

You can then grab these from `$_GET` in a.php and b.php

Is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This cab be achieve using cURL function in PHP...see the below references..

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your z.php file to perform connection to a.php and b.php.
You can retreive IP and location though $GET variable, an example would be :

- You call z.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&location=yyyy
- z.php makes an HTTP request (you can use [cURL](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl) for that)
- z.php waits for the response and send it back to your original script.