# Sending parameters to other sites

Tags: php

This question is related [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883338/how-can-i-send-a-date-from-one-site-to-other-sites). Let me change the question a bit, I didn't really explain myself properly. What I intend to do is get z.php to read a text file called 'sites.txt' which has a list of sites:

```
site1.com/a.php
site2.com/b.php
site3.com/c.php
```

to execute the URLs in the sites in 'sites.txt' I want it to go through `siteA.com/z.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx&location=UK` (z.php will then read 'sites.txt'). All sites in the 'sites.txt' file will be executed as

```
site1.com/a.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx&location=UK
site2.com/b.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx&location=UK
```

I have tried looking around but couldn't find what I was looking for.

```
site3.com/c.php?ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx&location=UK
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (not tested)?

```
$handle = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $site = fgets($handle);
  $sitestats = fopen(trim($site) . "?ip={$_GET['ip']}&location={$_GET['UK']}", 'r');
}
fclose($handle);
```

You probably want to validate the GET variables as well

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP Requests**

Use the [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library to hit the other sites from z.php.

cURL allows you to issue HTTP requests to another web server from within a PHP script.

**IP Address**

You can get the client IP address with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. If you get the IP address from user input, then you must filter it.

**Reading the Text File**

Probably the easiest way to read the file is with the `file()` function, which reads each line into an element of an array. The following line of code strips out the newlines and ignores empty lines.

```
$lines = file('sites.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Then you just iterate through the lines and do what you need to do:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using file_get_contents in combination with the environment variable query string:

```
<?php
 // read your site urls into an array, each line as an array element
 $sites = file('sites.txt');

 // walk thru all sites, one at a time
 foreach ($sites as $site) {
   // combine your incoming query string (?ip=...&location=...) with your site, by appending it to $site
   $site .= '?' . getenv('QUERY_STRING');

   // prepend $site with http:// if it is not in your text file
   if ( substr($site, 0, 4) != 'http' ) {
     $site = 'http://' . $site;
   }

   // open the url in $site
   $return = file_get_contents ($site);
 }
```

If you use this in your z.php, you will forward all the incoming get url parameters to your urls.